# Integral of function $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x = 1$}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, recreational-mathematics

Need to find the integral of the function $f$ where for $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x = 1$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I think it's zero because $f(x)$ doesn't have any area under it. I think I'm stuck other than that though.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE Please explain the question and show your attempt to get a good reply.

Comment: Over what interval? Show your thinking, even if you're sure it's wrong. You'll get help if you've showed you've tried.

Comment: f(x) has no area under it so the integral of it will always be zero?

Comment: In addition to the flaws in your question that have already been pointed out, I would note that the tags are off (this isn't really "analysis", more like "calculus", and it doesn't look like "recreational" to me), and the question should be in the body, not just in the title (so you wouldn't need that "letters" nonsense).

Comment: Over the real numbers?

Comment: This isn't a homework question that I'm working on so I think it is recreational.

Comment: Are you interested in determining whether the function is Riemann Integrable and also specify the domain of the function. One more things please reconsider the tags.

Comment: I don't know what the tags should be. I also don't really know what those words mean. @StammeringMathematician

Comment: @JustinTang Which course are you taking.

Comment: What is the domain of integration? What sort of integral?

Comment: I think it should just be the real numbers @copper.hat

Comment: I'm taking calc 3 rn

Comment: Is this Riemann or Lebesgue integration?

Comment: @copper.hat I don't know what those are

Comment: Hmm, is this a homework problem? Without having a definition it is hard to give an answer. What sorts of functions do you know how to integrate?

Comment: The answer is zero regardless, but to prove it you need some definitions or something to compare with...

Comment: I only know how to integrate functions that I know are the derivative of some elementary function. I thought that the integral was just the inverse of the derivative, but if there are two different functions that integrate to the same function, I don't think that definition works anymore

Comment: Hmm, it is difficult to give you a precise answer without having a formal definition. Are you familiar with the idea that $\int_a^b f(x)dx + \int_b^c f(x)dx = \int_a^c f(x)dx$.

Comment: How did this question come about? A formal definition involves a good bit of work, typically involving partitions, $\sup$s, $\inf$s, upper & lower sums.

Comment: Yeah. Is riemann integral related to reimann sums? I know those. I was thinking about some other math hw problem and this came up.

Comment: Well, if you are using Riemann integration, you need some interval as the domain. We can pick $[-1,1]$ to be definite. Then we pick a partition $P$ and compute the lower Riemann sum $L(f,P)$ and the upper Riemann sum $U(f,P)$. We find the $\sup $ of the lower sum and the $\inf$ of the upper sum. If they are the same the function is (Riemann integrable) and the common value is the value of the integral.

Comment: In your example, we always have $L(f,P) = 0$. If we pick a partition $P=(-1,-\epsilon, \epsilon, 1)$ with $\epsilon>0$, then $U(,P) = 2 \epsilon$ and since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we see that $\inf_P U(f,P) = 0$ and so the function is integrable with value zero.

Comment: Anyway, it is past my bedtime, I need my ugly sleep. Good luck.

Comment: What is sup and inf?

Comment: Thanks I guess.

Comment: A sort of generalisation of $\max$ and $\min$. For example, the collection of numbers $(0,1)$ has no $\max$ or $\min$ but $\inf (0,1) = 0$ and $\sup (0,1) = 1$.

Comment: Wow, the PC police removed my rather innocuous comments!

Comment: @JustinTang: Did any of the comments help? It is easy to post a technically correct answer, but without the appropriate tools that will be of no help to you.

Comment: To help connect the Question to a definition of "integral", you should describe how you understand Riemann sums apply to your problem.  Then we can give you a reasoned mathematical argument to justify your intuition.  Note that while  a *definite integral* will be zero, this function does not have an antiderivative (an indefinite integral).